# Class template interaction

Tags: c++, templates, typename, class-template

I am actually fairly certain the answer to my problem can be found in one of the previously created threads.  In particular, [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132) which has a great explanation on template/typename disambiguation.  I am however at a loss because I am not actually able to extend the concept to my code which is class templates that interact with each other.

In this thread, I think I see the same error as I get in my code.  Why is the answer to define the typedef using `A<B>` where B is the class, as opposed to `A<T>` where T is the typename template we actually want to have.

Nevertheless, I have tried these options to no avail.  Here is the code. Thank you for your help.

```
#include "testTemplateA.h"
template<typename A>
class testTemplateB {
public:
    // none of these work
    typedef testTemplateA<A> templateType;
    typedef typename testTemplateA<A> templateType;
    typedef typename testTemplateA<testTemplateB> templateType;

    testTemplateB(templateType& TA) {}

    ~testTemplateB(void) {}
};

#include "testTemplateB.h"
template<typename A>
class testTemplateA
{
public:
    testTemplateA(void) {}

    ~testTemplateA(void) {}

    void callUponB(void) {
        testTemplateB<A> g = testTemplateB<A>(this);
    }



};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks more like a circular dependency problem than a template syntax problem.  As long as you can define one class with the other incomplete, you can do something like:

```
// Begin testTemplateA.h
#ifndef TEST_TEMPLATE_A_H
#define TEST_TEMPLATE_A_H

template<typename A>
class testTemplateA
{
public:
    testTemplateA(void) {}

    ~testTemplateA(void) {}

    void callUponB(void); // Can't be defined here!
};

#include "testTemplateB.h"

template<typename A>
void testTemplateA<A>::callUponB(void) {
    testTemplateB<A> g = testTemplateB<A>(this);
}

#endif
// End testTemplateA.h

// Begin testTemplateB.h
// Yes, the include is outside the define guard.
#include "testTemplateA.h"

#ifndef TEST_TEMPLATE_B_H
#define TEST_TEMPLATE_B_H

template<typename A>
class testTemplateB {
public:
    typedef testTemplateA<A> templateType;

    testTemplateB(templateType& TA) {}

    ~testTemplateB(void) {}
};

#endif
// End testTemplateB.h
```

If a source file includes just testTemplateA.h, it will see the class template definition for `testTemplateA`, then include the entire contents of testTemplateB.h, then see the member definitions in testTemplateA.h that depend on `testTemplateB`.  If a source file includes just testTemplateB.h, it will immediately begin with testTemplateA.h, which will still include testTemplateB.h in the middle and get the same results.  If a source file includes both in either order, the second one will have no effect since both have already been included.

You only need the `typename` keyword like that in front of a name including at least one `::` token.

One other thing: your constructor `testTemplateB(templateType& TA);` expects a reference, but your statement `testTemplateB<A> g = testTemplateB<A>(this);` passes the pointer value `this`.

Comment: As soon as I read the circular mention I thought to myself it would probably contain the answer and I think it does.  I might however need some more explanation if you please.  The separation of the prototype and the actual method is separated similar to what the header/object file would do yet I was told one could not use such style when using class templates.  Do you care to explain why it is allowed in this case?

Comment: @user3417339: You can define a member of a class template (or template member) outside the class.  It just still needs to be in a header file that gets included, not in a source file that's not visible to other source files.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
typedef testTemplateA<A> templateType;
```

You are creating a template class using Class Template

```
template<typename A>
class testTemplateA
```

While creating a template class you need to give actual type. So it should be like this,

```
typedef testTemplateA<< testTemplateB<int >> templateType;
```

It is adviced to use "**class**" if it is expected T will always be a class, with "**typename**" if other types (int, char*, float whatever) may be expected. Consider it a usage hint.

Comment: No, `testTemplateA<A>` is a valid type (which depends on the template parameter `A`).

Comment: Agree!! But because of circular dependency, it was giving compile time error.